# Pause before executing a jQuery action

Tags: jquery, delay, pausing-execution

I'm putting an AJAX form in a bootstrap modal.  After the form successfully submits, I want to display a success message and then hide the modal.

I first set the success message as msg, then replace the form with the message, and finally, I hide the modal in the three lines below.

```
var msg = '<div class="alert alert-success" id="' + $(replace_selector).attr('id') + '">Feedback Submitted</div>'
$(replace_selector).replaceWith(msg);
$el_parent.modal('hide');
```

How can I create a delay between the second and third lines of code?  I tried [delay](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) but wasn't able to get it working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $(replace_selector).replaceWith(msg);   
    setTimeout(function(){
        $el_parent.modal('hide');
    }, 3000);
```